# how to redirect without leaving facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, bots

I am developing a chatbot in facebook messenger which will allow you to allow to place orders easily and even make payment.
I need to redirect without leaving messenger:

[image]

[image]

something like that

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What you got there looks simply like the Receipt template, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/receipt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you use the botman studio framework, simply enable your template to enable-> extension:

```html
$question = GenericTemplate::create()
->addImageAspectRatio(GenericTemplate::RATIO_SQUARE);

foreach ($objects as $object) {
  $question->addElements([
    Element::create($object->code)
    ->image($object->arch)
    ->addButton(ElementButton::create("Information")->payload($object->code)->type("postback"))
    ->addButton(ElementButton::create('add to car')->url('')->enableExtensions('true'))
    ->addButton(ElementButton::create("back")->payload("back

      > and add your domains to your whitelist from config / botman / facebook.php


      ")->type("postback"))
  ]);
}
```

> and add your domains to your whitelist from config / botman / facebook.php:

```
 'whitelisted_domains' => [
    'https://',
    'https://',
],
```

> Add your domains on your facebook page, entering messenger settings, whitelisted_domains and that's all